# Android: Find a value inside an Array with a "a like" value

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I'm having problem with this part

My Code:

```
String[] sample = {'name=NAME', 'add=ADD', 'age=AGE', 'gender=GENDER'};

for(int a = 0; a < sample.length; a++) {
    if(Arrays.asList(sample).contains("name")) {
        Log.d(tag, "successful");
    } else {
        Log.d(tag, "failed");
    }
}
```

When I'm using this code, it doesn't return `true`, but when I use `.contains("name=NAME")`
it returns `true`.

Is there any possibility to compare a string value using not too specific string?

BTW, those string values came from a file.txt.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *not too specific string*? Try to clarify your question.

Comment: @Magnilex I think Machee is considering `name` as a object and `NAME` as its value

Comment: @Vimal Bera, yes, that is what I want to do.

in my array, I'm create a "virtual" declaration. small letters as variables and big letters is there value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Arrays.asList(sample) you will have a list containing the String "name=NAME" hence it doesn't contain the String "name"

You should loop over the array (not needed to create the list)

```
boolean found = false;
for (String s: sample) 
    if (s.contains("name")) 
        found=true;
```

Comment: Hi sir, I've tried your code. Luckily it found my value "name"
but my problem now is, I can't get what position of that string in my array :(. But thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

`.contains` method will check whether the object is present in the ArrayList or not.

Here in your case objects are : "name=NAME","add=ADD","age=AGE", "gender=GENDER" which are of `String` type. So it is obvious that it returns false.

For you, better practice is to create a class named `Person` which has attributes like name,add,age and gender. Then store the object of it in `ArrayList` and you can check whether object is in ArrayList of not using `.contains()` function. Like below :

```
class Person{
String name;
String add;
int age;
String gen;
    // All getters and setters methods will be here.
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Person p = new Person();

    //Here you can set the properties of person using p.setXXX() methods
    //Now suppose you have ArrayList of Person object named "per" then you can check
    // whether Person exist in it or not using contains like below

    per.contains(p) //returns true if per contains object p

    //or you can check name by below code

    for(Person temp:per){
            if(temp.getName().equals(name)){ //returns true if name matchs with Persons name
                      //do something
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you direct me on how to do this?

BTW, I'm a student and a month old android developer.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value based on key:

1) You can use HashMap object

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create hash map
    HashMap newmap = new HashMap();

    // populate hash map
    newmap.put("name", "abcde");
    newmap.put("age", "XX");
    newmap.put("Gender", "Male");

    // get value of key Gender
    String val=(String)newmap.get("Gender");

    // check the value
    System.out.println("Value for key 3 is: " + val);
  }    
}
```

2) You can also use Map object

```
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("name", "abcde");
  map.put("age", "XX");
  String val=(String)map.get("name");
```

3) You can also use two dimentional array of string

```
  String data = "name=Name,age=Age";
  String[] rows = data.split(",");
  String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][]; 
  int r = 0;
  for (String row : rows) {
     matrix[r++] = row.split("\\=");
  }
  System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);
```